# Objects in a 3d sphere coordinates to 2d

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm making a 3d compass that tracks camera movements in three.js. [Here's an image of the compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIvqq.png)

In the image, the pie slice is the FOV of the camera and the small, pink circles are the objects in the scene. The scene is a sphere, and the objects are all along the edges of the sphere. Given the x, y, and z positions of the objects, how do I get the relative positions in a 2d circle? I tried getting the angle: 
    `yAngle = Math.atan(xpos / zpos)` and then getting the x and y positions on the circle by doing: `x = radius * Math.cos(yAngle), y = radius * Math.sin(yAngle)`, but that isn't getting the correct positions. I think I can do something with three.js projections?

I would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: Since your compass is 2D, is it considered a top-down representation of your camera's orientation? Assuming yes, is your camera's movement planar, or will you need to indicate whether an object is above/below the camera's horizon?

Comment: No – Since it's 2d, I'm just going to ignore above/below camera's horizon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have several objects in space, including your camera. If you view the scene from the top-down perspective of your camera, and you're ignoring whether objects are above/below your camera's horizon, then you can consider the object's positions in terms of X/Z (remember your look direction is along the camera's Y axis).

**Getting Object Positions In Camera Space**

It's relatively simple to get the 3D position of an object relative to another. In this case, you want the position of an object relative to your camera.

```
// keep this somewhere accessible to your function scope
var tempObjectLocation = new THREE.Vector3();

// later in your code...

tempObjectLocation.copy(yourObject.position);

// only need to do this if your object isn't already in world coordinates
yourObject.parent.localToWorld(tempObjectLocation); 

// put the vector in camera space
camera.worldToLocal(tempObjectLocation);

// tempObjectLocation now contains the object's position in camera space
```

**Getting The Position On The Compass**

Now that you have the object's position in camera space, you can either eliminate the Y component, or use it to detect if the object is above/below the camera horizon. In your case:

```
tempObjectLocation.y = 0;
```

You now have a vector in X/Z. Let's say its value is `{x: 15, y: 0, z: 8}`. Let's also say your compass uses a radius of `5` to place the object indicators around the outside edge. Simply set the length of the vector.

```
tempObjectLocation.setLength(5);
// tempObjectLocation is now {x: 4.411764705882353, y: 0, z: 2.3529411764705883}
```

The X and Z values now represent the indicator position on your compass, where `{x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}` is the center of you compass. (You may need to map X/Z => X/Y, or apply other transformations, depending on how you draw your compass.)